# How to select the max value for a column that is in a multiindex in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select the highest 't' for every trial but i'm struggling to find a way to call 't' as it's in the index. I've tried df_paths['t'] and things similar to that but i keep getting keyerror: 't'.

the dataframe looks like this (user, trial and t are multiindex):

```py
                  x    y
user trial t            
1    1     0.0  0.1  0.2
           1.2  0.3  0.5
     2     0.0  0.1  0.2    
           1.0  0.2  0.3
2    1     2.5  0.3  0.2
     2     0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Idealiy i would like the output as a list [1.2 ,1.0, 2.5, 0.0] so that i can count how many values are above 1 and store that in a variable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_index(level=['trial','t'], ascending=False)
         .groupby(['user','trial'])
         .head(1)
         .sort_index())
print (df1)
                  x    y
user trial t            
1    1     1.2  0.1  0.2
     2     1.0  0.2  0.3
2    1     2.5  0.3  0.2
     2     0.0  0.0  0.0
```

EDIT: For `t` values in index use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), last convert to `list`:

```
t = df1.index.get_level_values('t')
print (t)
Float64Index([1.2, 1.0, 2.5, 0.0], dtype='float64', name='t')

L = t.tolist()
print (L)
[1.2, 1.0, 2.5, 0.0]
```

With index is possible count by [`Index.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html):

```
print (t.value_counts())
0.0    1
1.2    1
2.5    1
1.0    1
Name: t, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Giulia - Like second solution? If not, can you add expected output Dataframe to question?

Comment: Is there a way to add these highest t values into a list so i can count them later?